# Why sorting on small numbers does not work?

Tags: python, pandas

It looks like Pandas sorting does not work any more:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import random
sample = random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=(100,))
ranking = pd.DataFrame(sample, columns=['random']).sort_values(by='random', ascending='False')
print(ranking.head())

      random
18  0.024665
71  0.028709
51  0.037635
48  0.038073
57  0.072323
```

I would instead expect the reverse order, because of `ascending=False`.

I'm using pandas 0.25.0.

Comment: String `'False'` is not Boolean `False`

Comment: `ascending="False"` will be interpreted as `ascending=True` since `bool("False") == True`

Comment: I'm blind. Switching between Java and python killed me on Friday morning.

Comment: @Erfan downvotes apply to the question, not the user. The question is IMO bad, because it's due to a typo in the user's code and is unlikely to be useful to other users, as the error has nothing to do with pandas or sorting (and I'm 99.9% sure there's a duplicate of this). SO would probably recommend to downvote this question, should it appear in a review queue.

Comment: @Erfan which, if you look, I did. The question is still bad, though.

Comment: I haven't taken it personally. Sometimes even closed questions can help other who made similar mistakes to find answer, but I agree the title is not very helpful in finding such mistakes, hence I agree: the quality of my question is bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is if `'False'` is not boolean, but string it is evaluate like `True`, so remove `''`:

```
print(bool('False'))
True

ranking = pd.DataFrame(sample, columns=['random']).sort_values(by='random', ascending=False)
print(ranking.head())
      random
44  0.997583
18  0.982477
19  0.979080
16  0.968516
15  0.962161
```